# JRE/JDK Changing Destination Folder

Tags: java

This may seem innocuous, but it's got me thinking...

I'm currently setting up a fresh Azure server for a project. It needs Java for a number of the things it will be doing. **One thing I like to do is put everything I'm running into a certain subfolder to keep things tidy and easy to find.**

I've put all sorts of other programs into this subfolder (*things I know enough about that I don't fear installing to non-standard locations*), but what about Java? **Is there a reason I shouldn't install it to a non-default location?** Is there something I don't know what would make this a bad idea?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no inherent problem with doing this.  You'll need to manage things like JAVA_HOME settings but other than that, it is pretty self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK and JRE are relocatable. You can move them without any problem. Make sure you point JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME to the proper folder.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I sort of suspected that it was okay, but I don't know any of the nuances of Java.